# Can't install ADT for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I don't have the rep to post screenshots but I'm not able to install ADT on Eclipse.    I have "unclicked" the "check updates" box but I am still told that the operation can't be completed.   I *did* go back and delete the whole ADT folder which had been working up 'til Friday; I reinstalled all of Eclipse.  In all seriousness, I guess my real question is:   is my best next step to get a big fast flash drive and install everything there, even if it works more slowly?

Comment: if you have problem installing the ADT plugin, get Eclipse with Android SDK directly from android download page.

Comment: Did that the first time. It didn't work. (Still doesn't; I am going from flash drive. It's slow, but it works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete eclipse and ADT then go to this site (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and download eclipse with sdk. Then go to download manager, download things you need and you're ready to go.
Hope this helps

Comment: Way better than that xD

Comment: Thanks! THat had been my first effort but it was still "finding" things that were "already installed" -- but not finding the ADK or letting me use it. Don't know if I botched the "uninstall" or what.   I found a way to delete the "already installed" so it's working... for now... hopefully next time I start it up it won't give me the "ADT? What ADT?" message...

Comment: Oops, afraid I need more information. Got all kinds of errors with the bundle (tried Juno and Luna, and yes, all the downloads necessary for all the parts).  "Unable to resolve target 'android-19' ... which for *some* but not all projects I fixed by right clicking and going to Properties and redoing the target... but that doesn't work for all (ignores my clicks) and I also get "Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arrycopy([CI[CII)V" (and I'm sure more).   Sorry...

Comment: In `default.properties file .

set target=android-19.

Comment: Yes, accomplished that for *some* projects; for others it ignored my attempts to set.  Decision: new Eclipse won't work with my old-version projects. It's working (Indigo, SDK tools 22.3 -- Juno and Luna give me "you must update to 23.0" but I can't figure out how to make that happen) on the work computer and looks like it will work from my Ultra Scan Disk (USB 3.0) flash drive.   (I already have the flash drive; slow is better than no.)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Android ADT Bundle from this following links

64 Bit - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5JTI8WeLk_dZWs0YzVja1R3U3c/edit?usp=drive_web

32 Bit - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5JTI8WeLk_dS1Rucmc4SVFqTjg/edit?usp=drive_web

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl consider this warning seriously, [`If you're a new Android developer, you should consider starting with Android Studio, because the ADT plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active development.`](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) If you still want to proceed, visit [Installing Android Plugin in Eclipse Offline & Online](http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-android-plugin-in-eclipse.html)

Note: That links to my own blog.

Comment: Thanks!  I started with a course in January... so I've been working with Eclipse since then. I got the impression Android Studio was still in "help us work out the bugs" stage, though.
    I did manage to find an option to delete the 'we can't help you these are already installed, but Eclipse can't find them' files, so I'm rolling, though I"m fearing that when I sign off and try to get back on, Eclipse will tell me again that it can't find the ADT files.